# CKFinder works localy but not on website

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have been writing code to include a page where people can write articles with an image they upload.

I have installed ckeditor_3.6.6.2 and ckfinder_php_3.0.0 in my website. I changed some configurations and everything was working on my xampp server.

When i upload my code to the website as update, i get the following error in the CKFinder File Browser:

> *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in
>   /www/d/dandelion/www/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php on line
>   16*

the code in this file is this:

```
<?php
/*
 * CKFinder
 * ========
 * http://cksource.com/ckfinder
 * Copyright (C) 2007-2015, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 *
 * The software, this file and its contents are subject to the CKFinder
 * License. Please read the license.txt file before using, installing, copying,
 * modifying or distribute this file or part of its contents. The contents of
 * this file is part of the Source Code of CKFinder.
 */

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder;

$ckfinder = new CKFinder(__DIR__ . '/../../../config.php');

$ckfinder->run();
```

Anyone can help me? I've tried almost everything :S

Comment: In CKFinder [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) are being used. You probably don't have php higher then 5.3.0

Comment: You'll need a webserver with PHP 5.4 or higher. Also check [CKFinder 3.0 system requirements](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/system_requirements.html) for more info.